# Webview link opens in external browser

Tags: android, webview, android-studio

I am a beginner in making android applications. I followed [THIS](http://techvalleyprojects.blogspot.no/2011/08/android-use-websites-in-your-app.html) tutorial on how to make a webview and I ran the app on my Galaxy Note 2 without any errors, but the link written in the code wants to open in a external browser when the app is opened. I want the page to be visible inside the web view in the application. How do i proceed to do this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
    WebView browser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

    // Enable javascript
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // load a webpage
    browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To help you better understand, I'm leaving my simple browser app code here for you.

Here **SimpleBrowser** is the MainActivity.

```
public class SimpleBrowser extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
WebView ourBrowser;
EditText url;
Button go, go_Back, go_Forward, refresh, clr_History;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browser_webview);

    ourBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WVBrowser);
    /* WebView Settings pretty important */
    ourBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ourBrowser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ourBrowser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    ourBrowser.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
    try {
        ourBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.mybringback.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Go);
    go_Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_GoBack);
    go_Forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_GoForward);
    refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_RefreshPage);
    clr_History = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ClrHistory);
    url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eT_webbrowser);

    go.setOnClickListener(this);
    go_Back.setOnClickListener(this);
    go_Forward.setOnClickListener(this);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
    clr_History.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_Go:
        String newWebaddress = url.getText().toString();
        ourBrowser.loadUrl(newWebaddress);

        /* Hiding the keyboard after the EditText data */
        InputMethodManager ipmm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        ipmm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(url.getWindowToken(), 0);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_GoBack:
        if (ourBrowser.canGoBack()) {
            ourBrowser.goBack();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btn_GoForward:
        if (ourBrowser.canGoForward()) {
            ourBrowser.goForward();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btn_RefreshPage:
        ourBrowser.reload();
        break;

    case R.id.btn_ClrHistory:
        ourBrowser.clearHistory();
        break;
    }
}
```

}
   Then have another Java file with name : ourViewClient.java and it should contain the below code:

```
public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true; // as mentioned in below notes, for your case., you do 'return false'
    }

}
```

**Android Manifest file:**
Ensure to have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` declared.
**browser_webview.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eT_webbrowser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Go"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Go" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_GoBack"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go back a Page"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mediumsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_GoForward"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Go Forward"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mediumsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_RefreshPage"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.90"
            android:text="Refresh Page"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mediumsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ClrHistory"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear History"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mediumsize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WVBrowser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I posted and see if there is something i can do with it. I am such a noob and I don't understand much of this :)

Comment: @Stumpp - I've edited my entire code for you. Please have a look and let us know if any more issues. I tried to be as clear as possible to help you. Hope you move forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have two errors after adding your code. In my main activity java at the line `browser.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());`  there is an error saying: setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient) in WebView cannot be applied to (play.test2.app.ourViewClient). Also in the ourViewClient.java the @override code gets a error: "Method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: @Stumpp - have a look at my code and utilize the same. My code should help you answer all of your queries

Comment: Perfect! It all made sense now and it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome Stumpp. Happy programming !

Answer (score 6):

Add this inside your oncreate():

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //open urls inside browser
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply solve this problem with this:

```
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
...
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("yoursite.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```